# Cut command doesn't redirect

Tags: bash, redirect, pipe, ubuntu-18.04, cut

Really curious why this doesn't work.  Spent the better part of a day trying to figure it out.

```
grep -r --line-buffered --include='*.txt' word . | cut -d ':' -f2-
```

this works fine and outputs things as expected

```
grep -r --line-buffered --include='*.txt' word . | cut -d ':' -f2- > reports/word.txt
```

This sends nothing to a file.  Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work, and perhaps how to get it to work

I am running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: If you want to remove the filename prefix, add option `-h` to `grep`.

Comment: Are you letting it finish or do you ctrl-c it?

Comment: What happens when grep starts searching the file its output is being redirected to?